# How to prove the blow up in a finite time of the classical solution following IBVP of semilinear heat equation?

Tags: partial-differential-equations, blowup

Let $p>1$ be an even number and $\Omega\subset R^3$ be a bounded boundary $\partial\Omega$. Using an energy argument to show that the classical solution $u$ to IBVP
\begin{equation}
\left\{\begin{array}{lll}
u_t=\Delta u+u^p, & x \in \Omega, & t>0, \\
\frac{\partial u}{\partial \nu}=0, & x \in \partial \Omega, & t>0, \\
u(x, 0)=u_0(x), & x \in \Omega, &
\end{array}\right.
\end{equation}
must blow up in a finite time provided that $u_0(x)$ is nonnegative and $\int_\Omega u_0(x)dx>0$.

I am stuck in it, how to deal with it? Are there some conferences?